# Laravel Api mult-tenant within mult-tenant

Tags: laravel, api, rest, multi-tenant

I am testing the laravel to replace an application I have.

I made the implementation of mult-tenant (https://tenancy.dev/docs/hyn/5.6) separating each tenant in a database and each tenant accessing through a subdomain.

This solves part of my problem. Because I can separate each business group in a database. However, within the same business group, there may be more than one business unit. I will give as an example mc donalds, that would be the business group and each of the stores would be the units. To resolve this issue I thought of creating a new tenant mechanism, this time, separating with a tenant_id in the database.

In that case, I would like to know from the most experienced if it would be a correct approach?

Another issue that arises is that there are users within the same business group who access more than one business unit. In this case, how to allow this access without having to re-register for each business unit?

I hope I have been clear in explaining the problem. If you need any more information let me know.

Any help is most welcome.

Thank you in advance to everyone who has read this far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, you will have to bring-in the concept of tenant hierarchy, For example

```
McDonald (Main Tenant)
    McDonald Seattle
    McDonald Oregon
    McDonald Newyork
```

In this way, you can have the parent tenant's contain all of the business user's and then assign them the access to the corresponding child tenants. In case you have a user working in multiple tenant's allow the user to set the tenant context post login to the root tenant. This helps you in identifying the contextual tenant and load the data accordingly.

There are many use-cases where the child tenant can have his own users. This might also come with the question like can i promote a user from a child tenant to a parent tenant like a regional manager that can manage a chain of restaurants.

Upon login, you can check if the user has a login for a single tenant (which ever in the hierarcy [parent / tenant]), in that case you can allow direct login, else prompt with the tenant context setting page to route him to the corresponding tenant.

In case of ACL, we might have to assign roles and permissions by tenant (by a tenantId column suffices) this helps a user play a manager role in one child Tenant (`McDonald Seattle`) and a Salesman role in (`McDonald Newyork`) tenant.

For example, I can have the following model. This will be set on choosing the tenant and from then on, I will be able to use the permissions / roles to validate from this context, so that no more db calls etc. This can be done in both the UI and also in the REST API layer (in the REST API layer, the place where we authenticate the user can setup this and have the API, Services, BusinessRules layers use this as a source of truth than hitting the database)

```
class UserContext {
    String userName,
    Guid Id,
    Guid TenantId,
    Roles[] TenantRoles,
    String[] Permissions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

It was very useful to clarify some doubts.

Right now I'm testing the package:

https://github.com/solutosoft/laravel-multitenant

I made some changes to the package. I created a user_idXtenant_id table, where I store the tenants that the user has access to. And when making a query / modification in a record, I check if that user has access to that specific tenant.

Do you have any other suggestions for implementing this concept exposed by you?

Comment: If you are having a tenant selection, i would setup the permissions for the user based on the tenant, so that for every operation under the context of a tenant, i don't have to lookup the tenant mapping. I will share sample code in the post

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. I was involved in another project, so I didn't answer before. I managed to solve using in part his reasoning.